# Frisa Lank: The most readable Stack Overflow yet!

Tags: discussion, design, april-fools

**Many thanks to whomever designed the "Frisa Lank" April Fool's Day theme for Stack Overflow!**

[image: Stack Overflow Frisa Lank 1080p]

It's by far the most readable and usable Stack Overflow CSS update I've seen yet!  Nice contrast.  Good use of color to indicate the various functions.  As someone who prefers utilitarian designs, I wasn't even bothered by the stars in the background.  They're not distracting, and give some depth to the page which somehow aids in focus!

Fantastic.

Comment: Yes, it's a revolutionary improvement to the website. Maybe the oval-link things on the left to the questions and tags should have a bit more margin though ;P

Comment: I unironically love this design. Really hoping they will keep it after April fools.

Comment: Yep, I completely like it also...  Pity it doesn't work on Meta also... // And the 3-D one is Buggy or Fake, it doesn't work (with 3-D Glasses), or only from 2m(+) from the Screen... // The 'Hotdog' one is also Buggy, can't switch to any other one after selecting it, need to refresh the Page... / But very nice April Fools Fun, I really like it...! :happy:

Comment: And it's faster!

Comment: It's an april fools thing? Thank raptor jesus, I wound up here trying to figure out how to turn it off. It's horrible.

Comment: And it solves the problem (for some) of the red dot on the review queues icon being too prominent!

Comment: @Fake Name: Yes, it could use some usability improvements. Buttons as circles??? Or maybe we are not hip and cool enough. But at least it *demonstrates* to us that there is a ***viable*** way we could get rid of the top bar (by collapsing it). The scroll bug caused by the sticky top bar is unacceptable.

Comment: I honestly really like the Frisa Lank theme. I did flip it to dark theme (thanks to my browser and my own bad eyesight) but I felt like it really was extremely readable. I want to opt in to this theme forever.